# Crystal reports complex summaries

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, conditional-statements, summary

We have a complex report that includes several calculations at different levels.

What I want to do is create a formula that says, "if any of the records at this level fulfill this condition, then colour the header in the level above red."

Normally I would do this by creating a formula (let's call it ConditionFulfilled) that says "if condition fulfilled, print 1, else 0", then in the higher group, "if {@ConditionFulfilled} >=1 then crred".

However, I can't summarize the Condition field because it's based on something that is already a summary.

If I just use a formula that says if condition fulfilled, then crred at the header level, it doesn't colour any of the headers red (because the condition isn't fulfilled in all cases) while a >= statement is colouring everything red (even if the condition isn't fulfilled.)

Has anyone encountered this problem with summaries before?  Can you suggest a workaround that will allow me to achieve the same effect without summarizing a summary?

Thank you.

Comment: What does the data look like and what are you summarizing?

Comment: Have you considered a cross-tab?